# Ubuntu 22.4 Wi-Fi keep disconnecting at random intervals

Tags: wireless, 22.04, network-manager

This started out of the blue but my Wi-Fi to my ubuntu machine and this machine only keeps disconnecting and not reconnecting(failing to reconnect?) but when i connect it manually it connects without a problem couldn't figure out why and nothing helpful on Google this is my network log I see this message on repeat:

```
     <info>  [1694100532.7575] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
     <info>  [1694100532.8532] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100532.8533] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100532.8666] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100532.8666] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100532.9315] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100532.9315] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100533.0319] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <info>  [1694100533.0319] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <info>  [1694100546.4894] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
     <info>  [1694100546.4895] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
     <info>  [1694100546.4906] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100546.4906] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100546.4999] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100546.4999] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100546.5878] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100546.5878] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100546.6882] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <info>  [1694100546.6882] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <warn>  [1694100557.7063] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
     <info>  [1694100557.7063] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694100557.7065] sup-iface[c9a27bde5062f3c4,0,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
     <warn>  [1694100557.7067] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
     <info>  [1694100557.7076] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694100557.7079] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694100557.7081] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'idan_janna_5Ghz' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
     <info>  [1694100557.7081] Config: added 'ssid' value 'idan_janna_5Ghz'
     <info>  [1694100557.7081] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
     <info>  [1694100557.7081] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
     <info>  [1694100557.7081] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'SAE FT-SAE'
     <info>  [1694100557.7082] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
     <info>  [1694100557.7082] Config: added 'ieee80211w' value '2'
     <info>  [1694100560.9448] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
     <info>  [1694100560.9448] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
     <info>  [1694100561.0442] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100561.0442] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100561.0597] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100561.0597] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100561.1903] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
     <info>  [1694100561.1903] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
     <info>  [1694100561.1904] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100561.1904] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100561.2959] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <info>  [1694100561.2960] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <info>  [1694100574.7407] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
     <info>  [1694100574.7407] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
     <info>  [1694100574.7424] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100574.7424] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
     <info>  [1694100574.7527] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100574.7527] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
     <info>  [1694100574.8426] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100574.8427] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100574.9425] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <info>  [1694100574.9425] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
     <warn>  [1694100582.7075] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
     <info>  [1694100582.7076] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694100582.7080] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
     <warn>  [1694100582.7083] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'idan_janna_5Ghz'
     <info>  [1694100582.7085] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694100585.8976] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694100585.8976] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
     <info>  [1694103752.6660] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'idan_janna_5Ghz' (029a79dc-a04a-48ce-9ad7-9238a3f4027d)
     <info>  [1694103752.6661] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="029a79dc-a04a-48ce-9ad7-9238a3f4027d" name="idan_janna_5Ghz" pid=2064 uid=1000 resul
     <info>  [1694103752.6661] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694103752.6663] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
     <info>  [1694103752.6665] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694103752.6667] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'idan_janna_5Ghz' has security, but secrets are required.
     <info>  [1694103752.6667] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694103752.6668] sup-iface[c9a27bde5062f3c4,0,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
     <info>  [1694103752.6676] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694103752.6678] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
     <info>  [1694103752.6680] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'idan_janna_5Ghz' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets neede
```

and this:

```
 <info>  [1694080814.6708] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
 <info>  [1694080814.6708] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
 <info>  [1694080814.7762] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 <info>  [1694080814.7762] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 <warn>  [1694080825.7059] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
 <info>  [1694080825.7060] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 <warn>  [1694080825.7064] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
 <info>  [1694080825.7073] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 <info>  [1694080825.7076] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 <info>  [1694080825.7079] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'idan_janna_5Ghz' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
 <info>  [1694080825.7079] Config: added 'ssid' value 'idan_janna_5Ghz'
 <info>  [1694080825.7079] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
 <info>  [1694080825.7079] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
 <info>  [1694080825.7079] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'SAE FT-SAE'
 <info>  [1694080825.7080] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
 <info>  [1694080825.7080] Config: added 'ieee80211w' value '2'
 <info>  [1694080828.9407] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
 <info>  [1694080828.9408] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
 <info>  [1694080829.0391] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
 <info>  [1694080829.0391] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
 <info>  [1694080829.0491] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
 <info>  [1694080829.0492] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
 <info>  [1694080829.1034] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
 <info>  [1694080829.1034] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> disconnected
 <info>  [1694080829.2039] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 <info>  [1694080829.2039] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 <info>  [1694080842.6845] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
 <info>  [1694080842.6846] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
 <info>  [1694080842.6867] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
 <info>  [1694080842.6867] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
 <info>  [1694080842.7009] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
 <info>  [1694080842.7009] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
 <info>  [1694080842.8359] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
 <info>  [1694080842.8359] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
 <info>  [1694080842.8363] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
 <info>  [1694080842.8363] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
 <info>  [1694080842.9415] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 <info>  [1694080842.9415] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
 <warn>  [1694080850.7078] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
 <info>  [1694080850.7079] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 <info>  [1694080850.7081] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
 <warn>  [1694080850.7083] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'idan_janna_5Ghz'
 <info>  [1694080850.7085] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
 <info>  [1694080853.8935] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
 <info>  [1694080853.8935] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```